# Blinking output with time on and time off Schneider User Function Block

Tags: automation, plc, ladder-logic

I'm trying to implement an LED flasher logic using the function block feature of the Schneider TM200 PLC. I think I was able to get very close to what I need by the logic below:

[image]

The problem with this logic is that it starts the output at off, that is, it leaves it off and only starts after the first cycle of time off. I need it to start the cycle on. Unfortunately, the User Role Block feature in the Schneider software doesn't seem to allow you to mention local timer contacts separately:

[image]

How could I create a function block for on and off time when the start should be turned on?

Comment: Why not just invert the output state? There is PLCs that in ladder has a function to invert the logic, if not... you could set a temporary memory internal of the block and then use one of its contacts in normal closed to activate the output itself.